# Optional parentheses in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I noticed that the optional parentheses in Coffeescript introduce a syntactic ambiguity.
For example, the code

```
prompt Math.max(2), 3      # no space after max
```

compiles to

```
prompt(Math.max(2), 3);    // one parameter to max(), two to prompt()
```

whereas

```
prompt Math.max (2), 3     # space after max
```

compiles to

```
prompt(Math.max(2., 3));    // two parameters to max(), one to prompt()
```

I.e. adding a space before the parameter list changes the grouping of the parameters.

Is this intentional? Are there other places in the language where a space makes a syntactic difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is intentional.

Space after variable in CofeeScript means: "apply the following list of arguments to this function.

Lets look to your code:

```
prompt Math.max(2), 3
```

It means: "apply to `prompt` two arguments: `Math.max(2)` and `3`".

```
prompt Math.max (2), 3
```

It means: "apply to `Math.max` two arguments: `(2)` and `3`, and then apply the result to `prompt`".

Lets see more complex example:

```
my_function (obj = other_function 1, 2), some_var
```

In this example bracket are necessary.

This feature allows you to write the same code in two ways:

```
my_function (my_array.map (x) -> do_smth x), some_var
```

is the same as

```
my_function my_array.map((x) -> do_smth x), some_var
```

I don't know about any other places in the language, where a space makes a syntactic difference. But there is a place, where brackets makes difference:

```
my_object = one: two: three: 'three', four: 'four'
=>
my_object = {one: {two: {three: 'three', four: 'four'}}}
```

and

```
my_object = one: {two: three: 'three'}, four: 'four'
=>
my_object = {one: {two: {three: 'three'}, four: 'four'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The parentheses mean completely different things in your examples.

```
prompt Math.max(2), 3
```

Here you invoke the `max` function with the sole argument `2`. The parentheses are part of the function call. It's clear that `max` will be called with this argument.

```
prompt Math.max (2), 3
```

In this case the parentheses are part of the *expression* `(2)` which will be simplified to `2`. You omit the optional parentheses of the function call.

So, is this intentional? Yes, I would say so, there's not much room for different interpretation. For further reference there's a [coffeescript style guide](https://github.com/polarmobile/coffeescript-style-guide). It doesn't explicitly mention that there should be no space between a function name and its parentheses but all the examples are written that way.

Comment: Thanks for the style guide link.